# How do I create a path in code to locate a file in a specific location? Delphi XE6?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

What is the procedure or method add a path to a file in the `{$I ...}` line?
I have a file that I want the compiler to be able to find.

For example, say I have downloaded a file named "abc.inc" that receives a file error as follows:

> F1026 File not found: 'abc'

The file in code is something like this:

```
{$I abc.inc}
```

My question is how do you write a file path in code to a particular folder in my project?

For example, let's say my file "abc" is located this path: project\comps\jcl\abc.inc

How would I write in code `{$I abc.inc}` "is located  in path comps\jcl\abc.inc  ?

I think I know how `{$I` functions... How to add/include/incorporate  "abc.inc" file into my project using code. How do I write a path in code?

Comment: {$I \comps\jcl\abc.inc}.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find jedi within my Delphi 5 file using XE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145897/cannot-find-jedi-within-my-delphi-5-file-using-xe6). This is the **third time** you've posted the same exact question; this time you've only changed the filename that's in the `{$I}` directive. **Don't** keep posting the same question again and again. Edit the original question, if you're not getting the answer you need.

Comment: That is not quite accurate but won't quibble with how it looks. I misinterpreted the Help file which suggests to ask a different q where necessary.  I 'deleted' 2nd q...My biggest mistake (of many), I think, was referencing same "jedi.inc" code again for question - How tell Delphi where to locate a file path...  I have over 82 errors in an old -but robust- D5 program written for me back in 2005.  Most errors are 'undeclared identifier' or 'file not found.'  I hope to tidy things up appropriately and will not ask same q more than once in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Include_file_(Delphi)):

> If the filename does not specify a directory path, then, in addition to searching for the file in the same directory as the current module, Delphi searches in the directories specified in the Search path input box on the Delphi Compiler page of the Project > Options dialog box.

This documentation text is vague at best. What actually happens if you specify a relative path, is that the path is taken to be relative to the file which contains the `$INCLUDE` directive.

So if the file to be included is not in the same directory as the source file that is including it then your options are to:

1. Specify the absolute path of the include file, or
2. Specify the path of the include file, relative to the source file containing the `$INCLUDE` directive, or
3. Add the directory containing the include file to the search path.

Comment: This answer is comprehensive.  I would like to add what Sertac Akyuz and MartynA and others have noted -and which directly refers to sample file location (...comps\jcl\abc.inc) - an absolute path would be written something like this: {$I C:\Delphi\comps\jcl\abc.Inc}.  Certainly it depends upon where file 'abc.inc' is located...

Comment: @Brent Item 1 of my list covers that

Comment: Yes of course. I only meant to spell it out for any newbies like me who either are unfamiliar with the term 'absolute path' or who would have benefited from seeing a path example as related to said file 'abc.inc'.

Comment: "absolute path" and "relative path" are terms used even outside of programming.